# Three.js drawImage from multiple view canvas WebGLRenderer onto multiple canvases

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, webgl

My problem is that I want to have only 1 WebGLRenderer, but have many camera views that can be placed in many unique canvases. In the example below I have 9 views that are in 1 canvas, each with unique cameras, scenes, and meshes which are then drawn onto their own canvases using the ctx.drawImage method. This method works, but drawImage is far too slow to even get 10 fps let alone the 60+ fps that is desired.

Is there any way around this problem that doesn't involve using the slow drawImage method or is there a way to speed up this whole process?

Thanks for the help and the example code is placed below.

http://jsfiddle.net/QD8M2/

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Three.js Test</title>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <script src="./three.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var renderer;
        var windowWidth, windowHeight;
        var numberMeshes = 1;
        var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

        var viewDemensions = {x: 3, y: 3};

        var views = [];

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {
            for (var i = 0; i < viewDemensions.x; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < viewDemensions.y; j++) {
                    var obj = {};

                    obj.left = i/viewDemensions.x;
                    obj.bottom = j/viewDemensions.y;
                    obj.width = 1/viewDemensions.x;
                    obj.height = 1/viewDemensions.y;

                    obj.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    obj.context = obj.canvas.getContext('2d');

                    document.body.appendChild(obj.canvas);

                    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 100/100, 1, 10000);
                    camera.position.z = 1000;
                    obj.camera = camera;

                    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

                    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 10, 10);

                    obj.meshes = [];

                    for (var k = 0; k < numberMeshes; k++) {
                        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff*Math.random(), wireframe: true });
                        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                        var scale = 2*Math.random();
                        mesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
                        scene.add(mesh);
                        obj.meshes.push(mesh);
                    }

                    obj.scene = scene;

                    views.push(obj);
                }
            }

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                preserveDrawingBuffer: true
            });

            // document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        }

        function updateSize() {
            if (windowWidth != window.innerWidth || windowHeight != window.innerHeight) {
                windowWidth  = window.innerWidth;
                windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
                renderer.setSize (windowWidth, windowHeight);
            }
        }

        function animate() {

            updateSize();

            for (var i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
                var view = views[i];
                var left   = Math.floor(view.left*windowWidth) * dpr;
                var bottom = Math.floor(view.bottom*windowHeight) * dpr;
                var width  = Math.floor(view.width*windowWidth) * dpr;
                var height = Math.floor(view.height*windowHeight) * dpr;
                view.canvas.width = width;
                view.canvas.height = height;
                view.canvas.style.width = Math.floor(view.width*windowWidth) + 'px';
                view.canvas.style.height = Math.floor(view.height*windowHeight) + 'px';
                view.context.scale(dpr, dpr);
                view.camera.aspect = width/height;
                view.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setViewport(left, bottom, width, height);
                renderer.setScissor(left, bottom, width, height);
                renderer.enableScissorTest (true);
                renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color().setRGB(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
                for (var j = 0; j < numberMeshes; j++) {
                    view.meshes[j].rotation.x += 0.03*Math.random();
                    view.meshes[j].rotation.y += 0.05*Math.random();
                }
                renderer.render(view.scene, view.camera);
                view.context.drawImage(renderer.domElement,left,bottom,width,height,0,0,view.width*windowWidth,view.height*windowHeight);
            }

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is the need to maintain single WebGLRenderer ?

Comment: because there is a hard limit in webgl that limits the number of possible concurrent webgl renderers

Comment: I am not aware of a WebGL specification limit on this, but there may be browser specific limitations like memory. Wouldnt it be just more efficient to have a single canvas and position these objects appropriately ?

Comment: The idea is to have many different canvases that can be placed independently of each other (overlayed, z-translated, rotated, etc.) but not by setting up an "overlay" canvas to do it.

WebGL generally will break at around 6-16 renderers depending on the size of each unique scene that is being rendered.

By using the multiple views in three.js, I can easily setup 1000+ viewpoints each with unique cameras and scenes. With unique renderers, I can only have a maximum of ~16 with almost nothing in them when WebGL crashes.

Comment: Good idea. But have you tried to use offscreen rendering (fbo), and position the textures then in different locations ? This would mean you use WebGL calls, not Canvas calls, but am certain it would be much faster.

Comment: Also just landed setting external context for three.js. Incase it helps, you can try it out instead of having multiple renderers. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/4360

Comment: oh wow, thanks for that change prabindh! It seems that multiple contexts might help me solve my problem. Is it possible that I can have a different offset for the individuals contexts so that if I am rendering a multi-view in three.js then one canvas can have one piece of the multiview while another canvas can have another? I'm not sure I am explaining myself well enough, but maybe a way to set setViewport and setScissor independently for each context? If this is not possible then thanks for all the help and glad to see the multi-context change make it in to three.js!

Comment: edit: It seems I slightly misunderstood, this change isn't multiple contexts but rather just setting the context. If this switching the context could be performantly done each frame, then I guess it might act like there are multiple contexts attached to 1 renderer.

Comment: As far as the offscreen rendering, that would still require the instantiation of a webglrenderer as far as I understand, which I am trying avoid creating more than 1 to prevent webgl crashes with large numbers of renderer canvases.

Comment: Offscreen rendering can be done with a single renderer using FBO, and the rendering can switch between FBO and to the regular display.

Comment: I've been searching around how to use FBO to do what you are describing with little success. Is there any page in particular that could give some insight on where to start using FBO to render to an additional canvas?

Comment: Will move this to an answer with more details,

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion as comments, using FBO with different views, and then using these textures as input to position in different views, might be suitable for your case. Please check. Note that this does `not` involve drawing to a buffer, then readingpixels back, and then applying it to a canvas.

EDIT1: Added pseudocode Using Three.js

`Create offscreen target`

rtTexture = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, ..);

`Create screen, material, and mesh`

mtlScreen = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {uniforms: { tDiffuse: { type: "t", value: rtTexture } },

mtl = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: rtTexture } );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( plane, function(rtTexture) );

scene.add( mesh );

`Now render to offscreen first, then to display`

renderer.render( sceneRTT, cameraRTT, rtTexture, ..);

renderer.render( scene, camera );

Refer to standard three example to get the full code - https://github.com/prabindh/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_rtt.html, and I posted a short slide on this at http://www.slideshare.net/prabindh/render-to-texture-with-threejs

`Approach With GLES2:`

Quick setup for FBO with GLES2 (trivial change to WebGL):

- ```
   glGenFramebuffers(NUM_FBO, fboId);
   glGenTextures(NUM_FBO, fboTextureId);
   glGenTextures(1, &regularTextureId);
  ```

Then comes setting up for drawing to offscreen buffers:

- ```
        GL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
          GL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTextureId[i]));
          GL_CHECK(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, globals->inTextureWidth, globals->inTextureHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL));
          GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
          GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));

          GL_CHECK(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboId[i]));
          GL_CHECK(glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTextureId[i], 0));
  ```

Then draw to offscreen buffer:

- ```
          //Bind regular texture
          GL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
          GL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, regularTextureId));
          add_texture(globals->inTextureWidth, globals->inTextureHeight, globals->textureData, globals->inPixelFormat);
          GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
          GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
           //Draw with regular draw calls to FBO
          GL_CHECK(_test17(globals, numObjectsPerSide, 1));
  ```

Now use this as a texture input, and draw to regular display:

- ```
          GL_CHECK(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTextureId[i]));

          GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
          GL_CHECK(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
          //draw to display buffer

         //Now get back display framebuffer and unbind the FBO
          GL_CHECK(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0));
  ```

https://github.com/prabindh/sgxperf/blob/master/sgxperf_test17.cpp

Comment: This is making more sense, but I am definitely not quite sure how to do this alongside three.js. This is slightly above my knowledge of webgl since I have never really used FBOs before, but I'll keep staring at this trying to get something working.

Comment: I posted my "solution" and if it is completely in the wrong direction from what you posted, could you please help me out in going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with. Not quite as pro as prabindh's answer but it is the only way I could come up with how to solve my problem.

Basically I used a WebGLRenderTarget to render each different view/scene onto the renderer and then copied the pixels out using readPixels onto a canvas. I tried to get web workers working to improve performance but couldn't get them to play nice with the image writing. My code is below.

If you meant something completely different prabindh, I would love some help on how to make this faster and/or better for my current use case.

```
var renderer;
var gl;
var times = [];
var windowWidth, windowHeight;
var numberMeshes = 10;
var dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

var viewDemensions = {x: 2, y: 2};

var views = [];

init();
animate();

function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
    renderer.autoClear = false;

    gl = renderer.getContext();

    for (var i = 0; i < viewDemensions.x; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < viewDemensions.y; j++) {
            var obj = {};

            obj.left = i/viewDemensions.x;
            obj.bottom = j/viewDemensions.y;
            obj.width = 1/viewDemensions.x;
            obj.height = 1/viewDemensions.y;

            obj.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            obj.context = obj.canvas.getContext('2d');

            document.body.appendChild(obj.canvas);

            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 100/100, 1, 10000);
            camera.position.z = 1000;
            obj.camera = camera;

            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 10, 10);

            obj.meshes = [];

            for (var k = 0; k < numberMeshes; k++) {
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff*Math.random(), wireframe: true });
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                var scale = 2*Math.random();
                mesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
                scene.add(mesh);
                obj.meshes.push(mesh);
            }

            obj.scene = scene;

            obj.widthVal = 100;
            obj.heightVal = 100;

            obj.imageData = obj.context.getImageData(0,0,obj.widthVal,obj.heightVal);

            obj.pixels = new Uint8Array(obj.imageData.data.length);

            // obj.ww = new Worker("ww.js");

            // obj.frames = [];
            // obj.prevFrame = 0;

            // obj.ww.onmessage = function (event) {
            //     var i = event.data.i;
            //     var imageData = event.data.imageData;
            //     views[i].context.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
            // };

            obj.target = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( 100, 100, { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter, format: THREE.RGBFormat } );

            views.push(obj);
        }
    }
}

function updateSize() {
    if (windowWidth != window.innerWidth || windowHeight != window.innerHeight) {
        windowWidth  = window.innerWidth;
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }
}

function animate() {

    updateSize();

    var i, j;
    var view, width, height;
    var sWidth, sHeight;
    var mesh;

    for (i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
        view = views[i];
        // if (!view.lock) {
        for (j = 0; j < view.meshes.length; j++) {
            mesh = view.meshes[j];
            mesh.rotation.x += 0.03;
            mesh.rotation.y += 0.05;
        }

        sWidth = Math.floor(view.width*windowWidth);
        sHeight = Math.floor(view.height*windowHeight);

        width  = sWidth * dpr;
        height = sHeight * dpr;

        var same = true;

        if (view.widthVal != width || view.heightVal != height) {
            same = false;
            view.widthVal = width;
            view.heightVal = height;
        }

        view.canvas.width = width;
        view.canvas.height = height;
        view.canvas.style.width = sWidth + 'px';
        view.canvas.style.height = sHeight + 'px';
        view.context.scale(dpr, dpr);

        view.camera.aspect = width/height;
        view.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(sWidth, sHeight);
        view.target.width = width;
        view.target.height = height;
        renderer.render(view.scene, view.camera, view.target, true);

        if (!same) {
            view.imageData = view.context.createImageData(width,height);
            view.pixels = new Uint8Array(view.imageData.data.length);
        }

        gl.readPixels(0,0,width,height,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,view.pixels);

        // view.ww.postMessage({imageData: imageData, pixels: pixels, i:i});

        view.imageData.data.set(view.pixels);

        view.context.putImageData(view.imageData,0,0);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}
```

Comment: It appears that when I add more views after init time, the webgl context will become lost and everything crashes. I'm starting to think that this problem may not really be solvable. Really too bad considering the limit on the number of contexts is so low in webgl compared to normal opengl.

Comment: This is absolutely not what I meant. readPixels is to be avoided. I edited my earlier post to show what I really meant, with Three.js references.

Comment: I understand what you are getting at, but I don't understand how this helps me with outputting the different views to separate canvases in the html. How you get "mtlScreen" onto a canvas in the html is the main idea that I am not understanding. (Sorry for not grasping this too well, this topic seems to be very poorly documented and I am no WebGL master by any means.)